# add facebook auth in my project. Kotlin + meta for developers

Tags: android, kotlin, facebook, authentication

I'm want to add facebook auth in the my project. when I click on the button:
i'm get this in the modal screen facebook: error, this app disabled. this appdisabled now and developer know this. when app will be sctivated repeat, you can auth

```
class loginPage : AppCompatActivity() {
        lateinit var bind: ActivityLoginPageBinding
        lateinit var launcher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
        lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
        private lateinit var callbackManager: CallbackManager




        private fun handleFacebookAccessToken(token: AccessToken) {
        Log.d("TAG", "handleFacebookAccessToken:$token")

        val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.token)
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d("TAG", "signInWithCredential:success")
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w("TAG", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(
                        baseContext,
                        "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }




        override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }





    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        bind = ActivityLoginPageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(bind.root)
        auth = Firebase.auth

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
                override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
                    handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.accessToken)
                }

                override fun onCancel() {
                    // Пользователь отменил вход через Facebook
                }

                override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
                    Log.e("FacebookLogin", "Error: ${error.message}")
                }
            })
```

i'm getting this in the modal screen facebook:

> error, this app disabled. this appdisabled now and developer know this. when app will be sctivated repeat, you can auth

Comment: Is that really the error message? I can't believe Facebook would use such broken English.